# problem with 4x4 matrix with big elements

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a homework for my linear algebra class at my university the thing is that we get a 4x4  matrix A then we have to find it's Transpose which is pretty easy and then find the matrix B=(A^T)*A also A=(A^T).The problem is that the matrix B's elements are all three figures making it very difficult to find the characteristic polyonymal, the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.no question actualy asks to find them but i can't find ways to answear them without doing so.things i try to prove are

(1) if the eigenvectors are linearly independent(i tried to do that by saing that it has 4 real distinct eigenvalues i can prove that the eigenvalues are real cause I found that B=B^T but i have no idea how to prove that it has 4 distinct eigenvalues)

(2) if the eigenvectors are rectangular(not sure if rectangular is the right terminology for what i want to ask i am greek) with each other (i would try to prove that the inner product of the eigenvectors equals zero by calculating them but as stated above finding the eigenvectors are hard to find with this matrix) a fraind of mine that found the eigenvectors by using some program then tried to calcute the inner products of the eigenvectors what he found was that the inner product was very close to 0 but since the eigen vectors were found by some program we can't be certain.

every and all advice is welcomed

Comment: It would help, for readability, if you could "break up" your question...(insert lines between thoughts: e.g., state the problem at hand - the question - then the "glitch" about B, etc...)

Comment: hope it is more readable now

Comment: Yes, that's an improvement...thanks!

Comment: Perhaps these hints will help to get you started.  $A^2-I=(A-I)(A+I)$ and $det(AB)=det(A)det(B)$

Comment: well i am not sure how det(AB)=det(A)det(B) could help i have seen it before but if i want to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of AB matrix i would need to find det((AB)-lI) right? except if det(AB) has some useful properties i am ignoring

Comment: A^2 - I = (A-I)(A+I) in my case it would be B - I = (A-I)(A+I) making it easy to find det(B-I) but again don't i need to find det(B-lI) or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If $B=A^TA$, then $B$ is symmetric, because $B^T=(A^TA)^T=A^T(A^T)^T=A^
TA=B$.  You should have a theorem that says symmetric matrices have real eigenvalues and the eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal (which is the term you want instead of rectangular).  If any eigenvalues do match, the eigenvectors can be chosen to be orthogonal as well.

Added:  here is a simple example to show what I mean about repeated eigenvalues and eigenvectors.  Let $M=\begin {pmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&2 \end {pmatrix}$  It has eigenvalues $1,1,2$.  The eigenvector corresponding to $2$ is $(0,0,1)^T$  Any vector of the form $(x,y,0)^T$ will be an eigenvector corresponding to $1$.  Note that all of these are orthogonal to $(0,0,1)^T$.  We can choose two orthonormal eigenvectors to span the space (the $xy$ plane), for instance $(\frac 35,\frac 45,0)^T$ and $(\frac 45,-\frac 35,0)^T$ (or, of course, the more mundane one).

Comment: about symmetric matrices i found that " a real n×n matrix A is symmetric if and only if there is an orthonormal basis of R^n consisting of eigenvectors for A." does this also mean that the eigenvectors of a nxn symmetric matrix construct an orthonormal basis of R^n?

Comment: @George0X: yes, the "if and only if" means you can go either direction.  To get orthonormal you need to scale the eigenvectors properly.  If the matrix has a repeated eigenvalue, the eigenvectors will span a subspace, so will not be automatically orthogonal, but can be chosen that way.

Comment: if a matrix has repeated eigenvalues does that mean that it's eigenvectors are linearly dependent or the eigenvectors can be linearly independent while the matrix has repeated eigenvalues?

Comment: @George0X:  You will have as many independent eigenvectors as the multiplicity of the eigenvalue.  My example above has multiplicity 2 and two independent eigenvectors.  Then any linear combination of the eigenvectors will be another one.

Comment: so in th above example we have 3 linearly independent eigenvectors?

Comment: @George0X:  Yes, I displayed them.